# What is the best practice for always running networking android app?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, android-networking

I am implementing app that is going to be always running and connected to server.

So the tablet has nothing to do other than running this app, and checking the server all the time for updates to show on the screen.

What can be the best practice to keep the app always running and connected?

In my experience, i have 2 options to solve this problem:

1. **Service** always running and connected to my activity to keep it updated.
2. Keep the work in **threads** within the activity, since the activity will stay always on. The app will be always on.

My questions are:

1. What is the best practice for keeping the app running all?
2. What is the best practice to keep the app connected ? Threads within activity? or service connected to activity?
3. Is there any preferable structure for such application type?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Battery is something that i will always take into consideration especially when networking task has to be done. So analyze the point where the is absolute necessary to connect to server.
2. Whenever you server needs to contact the device use GCM push notification that will save your battery juice which you will spend in polling the server

Well for

> Service v/s Thread

is concern the use service in which you should spawn worker threads which will perfrom the networking task
these threads will notify the main service thread when they are done for that you need to user Handlers in android

i will favor service over thread because if you close the activity network request will still be fulfilled once request is complete save it in some storage form(database/share pref/content provider) and retrieve it from them. Once you are done dont for get to destroy the service by all stopSelf a appropriate point or else the service will keep exhausting you phone resource. which will make you app a bad citizen.

A simple implementation of the about pattern i mentioned is IntentService which will automatically spawn the worker thread i.e you just have to override handleIntent method and do all the heavily lifting there which will not be on main thread. And IntentService kills it self when if finds itself doing nothings
The question which you have asked to my understanding is related to syncing with server you can find more about in from android docs
http://developer.android.com/training/building-connectivity.html

Answer (score 1):

If you read the official docu from Android. The best solution is using a service for your kind of app. It's prepared to run continuosly in background. You can implement it to check the network in a transparent way and you can bind the information to another activity. Furthermore, it's more scalable if later you want to change your connection or requirements (it won't affect to your apps activities).

EDIT.
The good point is, that if someday for a reason your app is not in foreground. The service can still be running. Services are prepared for long running tasks http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Could you please cite the android docu so i may read it. Additionally, the app does not need to be in the background, it will be always running also in the foreground. thank you